# How can I do where clause containing json in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

For example, I have a column named json in table A

Json column contains json data like this :

```
record 1 : {"dept_code": "012", "unit_code": "22"}
record 2 : {"dept_code": "013", "unit_code": "23"}
etc
```

I want to take the data records with json column that contain dept_code = 012

```
SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE json = ...(looking dept_code = 012)...
```

How can I do that?

Note :

I tried to find answers on the site stackoverflow, but I did not find it. So I make this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
SELECT * FROM table_A where json like '%"dept_code": "012"%';
```

Comment: Searching with wildcards (%) may lead to unexpected results on complexer scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure `JSON_CONTAINS` is what you want.  [View the docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

I don't have a sandbox to test this right now, but your example would translate to something like:

```
select * from table_A
where json_contains(json, '012', '$.dept_code')
```

Since dept_code is a property of the object stored in the json column.

Comment: It does not work. When the query is run, there exist error like this : `Error Code: 3141
Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "The document root must not follow by other values." at position 1.`

Comment: @mosestoh try `where json_contains(json, '"012"', '$.dept_code')`, i.e. wrap your 012 in additional quotes since your json value there is also a string. This solved _my_ problem with the same error message at least.
The answer you've accepted with that LIKE is very racy.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ...WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`json `, '{"dept_code " : "012"}')
```

Comment: It does not work. When the query is run, no records are displayed